# Is there any dataset available for similar posts recommendation like Facebook, Instagram and Twitter?

Tags: dataset, artificial-intelligence, data-science, recommendation-engine, kaggle

I want to build a similar post recommendation system that a user sees after performing some activity on the news feed. For example: If he/she spends more time on sports posts, giving him/her sports recommended post so I would like to get help on what kind of dataset do I need to build a post recommendation system that a user likes to see. I am confused on should I build a dataset of my own if yes how can I build these recommendation posts? Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score -1):

Hello and welcome to the forum! I recommend against building a dataset of your own as real world datasets have certain properties (distribution, missing data, noise) which are quite hard to replicate artificially.

You included Kaggle in your tags. Why don't you use it? It looks perfect for the job. [Here](https://www.kaggle.com/tags/recommender-systems)'s a list of options with the #recommender-systems tag.

[This one](https://www.kaggle.com/fabiendaniel/film-recommendation-engine) and [this one](https://www.kaggle.com/laowingkin/netflix-movie-recommendation) are about films. [This other one](https://www.kaggle.com/gspmoreira/news-portal-user-interactions-by-globocom/home) is about user interactions with a news platform.

If this answered your question, please don't forget to accept it by clicking on the Tick button at the left of the answer. Have fun!